# Nested Windows Job Objects: how to query limits imposed by a parent job object

Tags: windows, winapi, process, limit

Let P be a process which is assigned first to a MS Windows job object J1 and then to another job object J2. So J2 is nested into J1.

Then limits are set for J1, e.g. [JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147.aspx).

Documentation says:

> If the job is nested, the effective memory limit is the most restrictive memory limit in the job chain.

How do I get the effective limit from within P without a handle to J1?

Calling [QueryInformationJobObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684925.aspx) with NULL as job handle gives information for J2 only.